# Electron React Boilerplate + Deeplinks Error: --require

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I'm needing help. Seems I've run into a weird error. I've searched the internet for days now with no luck. I've posted in different discords as well.

### The Problem

I'm using the [Electron React Boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/tree/main) (ERB) and wanting to use the [DeepLinks](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/launch-app-from-url-in-another-app) functionality of electron as a Firebase Auth workaround, but after following the electron docs I get this error entering into the browser electron-fiddle://open

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcD5r.png)

Any ideas? I'm going crazy! What is this `--require` bit of the path? I've searched all over the RBE code and can't find any references to it...

### What I've Tried

- The app runs normally outside of trying to access through a url
- I have confirmed it's something in the ERB code as I was able to create from scratch an electron app and I got the desired effect.
- My code is the exact same as the ERB template here, save some react components and some things happening in main.ts on the ipcMain side of things.

### Possible Culprit

I'm wondering if this is something to do with the fact in ERB there isn't a renderer.js file as it goes through the webpack.config.renderer.dev.ts file and does something weird/unexpected in there?

Here is the link to the official Electron-React Boilerplate repo:
[Electron React Boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate)

I've changed nothing in the webpack files which you can find in .erb\configs
[Webpack folder](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/tree/main/.erb/configs)

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
if (process.argv.length >= 2) {
  app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('yourapplink', process.execPath, [
    '-r',
    path.join(
      __dirname,
      '..',
      '..',
      'node_modules',
      'ts-node/register/transpile-only'
    ),
    path.join(__dirname, '..', '..'),
  ]);
} else {
  app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('yourapplink');
}
```

Credits to: https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/issues/3245#issuecomment-1465781604